# C++ Builder Syntax Highlighter

Tags: c++, components, c++builder, richedit

I have searched on the Internet how to do this, but I can't find how.

I need to colour specific words in RichEdit, such as the words `false` and `true.`

Comment: Pro tip: google your subject line (after spelling it correctly).

Comment: Aside from what Jesper had to say you should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions about a codding issue. If you have not tried any code thus far then you are asking your question a bit prematurely.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I wanted something better then Memo editor so I needed full control over rendered and edited stuff so I have my own text editor class which renders to bitmap (and catches mouse and keyboard events) and mimics Borland IDE editor features (rectangular select included). I represent Syntax highlight like this: [missing syntax-highlighting for x86 assembly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348110/2521214)  So in case you want to code it on your own create similar tables , then decode which type of string you got and chose its color for rendering accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRichEdit` is not well-suited for syntax highlighting (use something more like [SynEdit](https://github.com/SynEdit/SynEdit) instead), but it *can* be done.  Basically, you need to highlight the desired text, and then set the selected text's attributes, like color and formatting.  You can do that with the `TRichEdit::SelStart`, `TRichEdit::SelLength`, and `TRichEdit::SelAttributes` properties.  Or you can use the corresponding Win32 API [`EM_EXSETSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788007.aspx) and [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230.aspx) messages directly.

See Robert Dunn's excellent article on this very topic: "Faster Rich Edit Syntax Highlighting".  The [Original article](http://bcbj.org/get_doc.php?art=articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm) first appeared in the [C++Builder Journal](http://bcbj.org) in October 1999, and is also [available for download](http://yacs.lebeausoftware.org/Papers/FasterSyntaxHighlighting.doc) on Robert's ["Yet Another Code Site"](http://yacs.lebeausoftware.org) website (which is archived on my website).